# efficient way to delete rows of big dataset in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm working with a big dataset 562792 obj of 803 variables
I want to subset my data based on the value of the sixth variable

my data set looks like this: (only a 5*10 subset of dataset)

```
           seq  start    end   name     score annotation        GC         NA       NA.1
PCPG_2 chr1  17238  17739 PCPG_2  4.406228   Promoter 0.6127745  0.4791137  0.4321641
LIHC_2 chr1 102709 103210 LIHC_2  3.472406     Intron 0.4491018 -1.4821049 -1.1310495
LIHC_3 chr1 136494 136995 LIHC_3  8.211594     Distal 0.7065868 -0.6996327 -0.5816772
TGCT_2 chr1 180653 181154 TGCT_2  7.718365     Distal 0.5588822  1.5983810  1.6995938
LGG_2  chr1 181202 181703  LGG_2 67.948112     Distal 0.7584830  2.9480593  3.2586839
             NA.2
PCPG_2  0.5570205
LIHC_2 -1.3443903
LIHC_3 -1.5895320
TGCT_2  1.6474305
LGG_2   1.7238597
```

basically I want to delete rows with "Promoter" annotation. I used this code to subset my data based on the "annotation" variable

```
promoters<-which(dataset[,6]=="Promoter")
dataset[-promoters,]
```

and R stooped responding and crashed
I also used command `subset` and R session stopped working.
as I am new with R I can not accurately detect the problem but I think It's because this big data takes so much memory.
can anyone help me with this or suggest a more efficient way to delete objects from dataset?

Comment: `dataset[ dat$annotation != "Promoter", ]` or `subset(dataset, annotation != "Promoter")` both should work. You may want to be careful using your `which` code ... if nothing is found, it will return `integer(0)`, and `dataset[-integer(0),]` returns zero rows, not what you intend. It might be better to use `logical` instead of `integer` indexing here; using your code, `dataset[!dataset[,6] == "Promoter",]` or `dataset[dataset[,6] != "Promoter",]` should also work.

Comment: @r2evans I did try both `dataset[ dataset[ ,6]!="Promoter", ]` and `subset` both crashed. I think that's because my dataset is huge. I tried this code with smaller dataset and It did work, but not on my actuall dataset.

Comment: I believe with `data.frame`s in general, deleting a row copies the entire frame into a new object. I thought that `data.table` might be able to avoid that, but [that issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635) appears to be still open. Yes, large data certainly raises challenges. I've heard (not tried) good things with [`disk.frame`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/disk.frame/index.html), but lacking that ... perhaps a database is a better fit for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`, from **dplyr**. The `filter()` is slightly more efficient than `subset()` and considering you have a huge dataset, this option may be more useful. Thus, you can use `filter()` like this:

```
dataset = filter(dataset, annotation != 'Promoter')
```

You can also use other conditions inside `filter()` using the condition operators (`&` and `|`), for example

```
dataset = filter(dataset, annotation != 'Promoter' & score < 8)
```

Ps.: remember loading the **dplyr** package (`library(dplyr)`), otherwise R will call a base funciton also called *filter*.

If you're still having troubles and R session crashes, you can run your code from the terminal, following these steps:

1. Edit you code;
2. Save it somewhere;
3. Run it from the terminal using the command **Rscript**. The following commands may help you:

   1. Change directory to the path where your code is, using: `cd "directory path"
   2. Run your code, using: `Rscript your_code.R

I hope it helps you.

Comment: How is `dplyr::filter` *"more efficient"*? While it'll rely heavily on the data *size*, `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(base=subset(diamonds, cut != "Ideal"), dplyr=filter(diamonds, cut != "Ideal"))` suggests that `dplyr::filter` takes 50% longer to do the same thing (and the results are identical).

Comment: (Okay, I see ... when I expand `diamonds` to be a bit larger, parity breaks out, and `dplyr::filter` is indeed a little faster on the larger end ...) For those who care, the funcs are about the same performance when I double the rows in `diamonds`. If I instead do 100x the rows (5M), `dplyr::filter` is around 24% faster than `subset`.

Comment: i have been trusting on literature, which says that `dplyr::filter()` is more efficient than the native `subeset()`. i appreciate a lot that you checked it out, @r2evans. thanks my friend!

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga thank you for your answer it was very clear. I used `filter` command in terminal with `Rscript` I got the following error `Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.`

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga the backtrace is 
 1. ├─dplyr::filter(dataset, annotation != "Promoter")
 2. └─dplyr:::filter.data.frame(dataset, annotation != "Promoter")
 3.   └─dplyr:::filter_rows(.data, ...)
 4.     └─DataMask$new(.data, caller_env())
 5.       └─.subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...)

Comment: as we can see, you have columns with the same name in your data. you should rename your columns and then use `dplyr::filter()`. since your data is huge, you can load it in R using `read.csv('data_path', nrows = 1)`. find a proper vector to describe the column names (without duplications). use this vector to rename your columns before applying `dplyr::filter()', in your main code.. if you could solve it and my answer helped you, give it an upvote, haha

Comment: ps.: if your filter uses only the 6th column of the dataframe, you rename it before applying the filter, like this: `colnames(dataset)[6] = 'annotation_filter'; dataset = filter(dataset, annotation_filter != 'Promoter')`.

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga thank you. I changed the column names but my code still takes too long to run and eventually R crashes.

Comment: @pegahT do you need all the columns of your dataframe? fala português?

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga yes  I need all of the columns. I need to do t-SNE clustering on the dataset after deleting "Prompter" rows